# No-Content-Script for chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I may be a bit of paranoid when it comes to installing chrome extension that request access to all my tabs and data. While a extension may be safe for the moment, a simple auto background update can make it a malicious virus and you won't even get notified about updates.

I would like to specifically whitelist all my extension to access the content pear webpages bases. Is there any such tool out there already (natively perhaps) before i start hacking my own extension to control it on my own.

That would leave me to my next question. Extension can be a bit secured running sandboxed environment and have no access to the "real" filesystem (not the virtual sandboxed filesystem) but could i write a NaCl plugin and have have full access and change the manifest file to change the [content_scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) settings? if so, could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand clearly your question, but let's calrify some things about extensions and how they can be dangerous:

**First**: If an extension updates and want to have new authorisations, Chrome will warn you and you can choose if you want it to be updated

**Second**: Chrome sandboxes extensions running on your computer

**Third**: The only authorisation that may represent a real danger for your computer are the ones requesting authorisation to "Access all data on your computer"
.

.

.
If you are really worried that some extensions may represent a danger for you (and I understand you), you can **restrict them to run on specific webpages** by doing the following:

**1**. Go to the extensions folders [C:\Users(YOUR USERNAME)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions(APPID)] and open the manifest.json file with any text editor

**2**. In "content_scripts" declaration, in "matches", specify sites where the extension will ONLY work on [ex:*://google.com/* will make extension be active ONLY for google.com]

You can even be more precise and set specific URLs/HTML pages (see more: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns)

Hope it helps!

If it doesn't, please clarify your question again.

Comment: Then we understand each other correctly. I'm aware about your first, second and third argument. Also how it can be solved (like you mention). Now what i would like to do is having a native chrome solution or build a extension that analyse all my extension and change content_script security accordingly as i surf the web. Having to enable it manually can be a bit of a pain if i would like to enable it for the second or third time

having auto update on extension that don't request new authorisations and already have "Access to all my data" that can be little unwanted

Comment: What about creating an extension checking to your favorites extensions directories and editing their manifest (like I mentionned before) with some search&replace function? You could replace all "full sites authorisations" with the restricted ones that you would like automatically. You could implement an "onchange" function (perform a check each time browser starts) by using localStorage to retain old value to check if any extensions updated and returned to old full authorisations. If you want to learn how to write to files: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-support